# AngularJS/Bootstrap color cells on conditon

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ng-class

I have a bootstrap table which contains various data. I want the last cell of a row to be colored in a special color if a certain argument equals a string.

So the code I use now looks like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in responseData">
        <td>{{data.title}}</td>
        <td>{{data.description}}</td>
        ...
        <td class="status" ng-class="{ 'available': data.status=='string1', 'taken': data.status!='string1'}"></td>
</tr>
```

And the css file:

```
.status{
padding:1px !important;
width:10px;
}

.status_available{
    background-color: green;
}

.status_taken{
    background-color:red;
    width:10px;
    height:100%;
}
```

But the td isn't colored in the initialized values. I use Chrome, and the developer tools show that the right class is on the td, but as mentioned the color is the standard one.

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

According to your css it should be:

```
<td class="status" ng-class="{ 'status_available': data.status=='string1', 'status_taken': data.status!='string1'}"></td>
```

or change you css to:

```
.status.available{
    background-color: green;
}

.status.taken{
    background-color:red;
    width:10px;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: thanks! but as mention above, the style gets applied to the td...but it doesn't show up somehow...

Answer (score 0):

Bad thing but - you can force it just by applying " !important" to your css rules like
background-color: red !important;
Probably some bootstrap styles are applied after you styles.